# Migration to Visual Studio 2019 causes crashes for a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have trouble with a WPF application after migrating from *Visual Studio 2017* to *Visual Studio 2019*.
The application consists of the following projects:

1. MyProject-> main WPF project
2. MyProject.Native -> project in C++ that makes usage of *OpenCV*
3. MyProject.Managed -> project that is a wrapper over *MyProject.Native*.

The dependency flow is: *MyProject* -> *MyProject.Managed* -> *MyProject.Native*.

The configuration type for the *MyProject.Native* is set to be a **.lib** and for the *MyProject.Managed* is set to **.dll**.

After migrating to the *Visual Studio 2019*, I had to change the *Platform Toolset* to *Visual Studio 2019 (v142)*. However, this causes some crashes saying that the *MyProject.Managed.dll* is missing from the *MyProject*.

The actual error is: *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject.Managed.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.*

Upon checking, I discovered that it is not the case.

Things I have tried:

1. Removing the project reference to the *MyProject.Managed* from *MyProject* and adding it again;
2. Cleaned/rebuild the solution;
3. Checked if the dependency is correctly added in *MyProject.csproj*;
4. Verified if the **.dll** file is present in the output directory after compiling;
5. Verified if the **.dll** file is present in the bin folder of *MyProject* after compiling the whole solution;
6. Verified if the *Path* to the **.dll** file is correct in the *Reference Properties* of *MyProject.Manged* reference from the *MyProject*;
7. Verified if the *Copy Local* is set to true;
8. Checked if the *Solution Configurations* and *Solution Platforms* is properly set. (Release/x64)

Notes:

1. The crash does not take place if the application is ran on a *Windows 10* environment (but it does on *Windows 7* and *Windows 8.1*).
2. If compiled using *Visual Studio 2017*, the application works fine.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue? If so, what was the fix? What am I missing

Comment: Have you tried deleting the obj and bin directories and completely rebuilding the app?

Comment: Maybe Win7 and 8.1 require additional runtimes? Something like this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: @KevinCook I have already tried that.

Comment: @Lennart I just did that and it seems to be working. The one that it was being shipped with my installer was Visual C++ 2017.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like Windows 7 and 8.1 are missing the latest Visual C++ (2019) Runtimes. You can download them from Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Visual Studio run it and have a look at the Modules Window and check if all is as you would expect.
If you can not use VS use a Software like Dependency Walker.
[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have used the Process Monitor and did not get anything with it. However, DependencyWalker showed me that something is wrong with my DLL, but it did not point me to my mistake.